# display more than one database query in .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating my first project using asp.net MVC  - I have successfully connected to the database and displayed the information on the index page. My question is how do I get more than one query result on the one index page
for e.g

```
SELECT student ID,first name,surname FROM STUDENT Notes WHERE student ID = 7
```

Do I  need to create new controllers/models for each query or need to add to the current and if I add to the current how would I do it? Below is the code I currently have in my controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //int sNumber = 1;
        List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {

            string query = "SELECT title, `first name`, surname FROM `STUDENT REGISTER`";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        customers.Add(new CustomerModel
                        {
                            // CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Student Number"]),
                            Title = sdr["title"].ToString(),
                            Name = sdr["first name"].ToString(),
                            Surname = sdr["surname"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }                

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return View(customers);
    }
```

Comment: Create a class and put all your customers and other items in it. Then pass that to your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new class with all the properties you want to display in your View.

**Example:**

```
public class StudentModel {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public strign Surname { get; set; }
    }
    public class MarkModel {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public int Mark { get; set; }
    }
    public class ResultModel
    {

      public StudentModel Student { get; set; }

      public List<MarkModel> Marks { get; set; }

    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //int sNumber = 1;
           var model= new ResultModel{
              Student = new StudentModel(),
              Marks = new List<MarkModel>();
           }

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string queryStudent = "SELECT id, title, `first name`, surname FROM `STUDENT` WHERE Id=1";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStudent))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;               
                    using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {    
                               model.student.Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["id"]),
                               model.student.Title = sdr["title"].ToString(),
                               model.student.Name = sdr["first name"].ToString(),
                               model.student.Surname = sdr["surname"].ToString()                     
                        }
                    }               
                }

                string queryMarks = "SELECT Id, `StudentId`, StudentId,Mark FROM `MARK` WHERE StudentId=1";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryMarks))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;               
                    using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            model.Marks.Add(new MarkModel
                            {
                               Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Id"]),
                               StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["StudentId"]),
                               StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["StudentId"]),
                               Mark = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Mark"]),
                            });
                        }
                    }               
                } 
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: on the view do I change it to `@model IEnumerable<ResultModel>` also what should my for look like     `@foreach (StudentModel Student in Model)
                              {
                                    <option>@Student.Name</option>`

Comment: @Michael. `Student` is a single item of `Model`. so you can get it by `@Model.Student.Name`.And `Marks` is a list item in `Model`. so you can get by `@foreach (var item in Model.Marks) {<option>@item.Mark</option> }`. Also your view model is now `@model ResultModel` not `IEnumerable` type.

Comment: if you need List of student then change `public StudentModel Student { get; set; }` to `public Lis<StudentModel > Students { get; set; }`. and change query execution as you done before and your view do as like as `Marks`.

Comment: I have made those change but I get the following error when trying to run the program with the loop 
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebApplication3.Models.ResultModel' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)'

Comment: this is what I am using at the top of the view `@model dynamic
@using WebApplication3.Models`

Comment: Sorry ignore the last comment - IT IS WORKING! thank you so much - I have spent 2 days trying to figure this out.

Comment: Is this the right way of doing it - should my database queries be in the controller or should I have them in the model for best practice in MVC?

Comment: @Michael. **No**. separate all into another class as a method  and return as `ResultModel`.

Comment: do you offer a teaching service - where I can pay you something per hour and you show me how to do things in MVC?

Comment: @Michael if you need more,then find some of my project in github repository https://github.com/ashiquzzaman/.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view model with two result set  for e.g. Student and Marks

```
public class Result
{

  public Student Student { get; set; }

  public Marks Marks { get; set; }

}
```

Load/Construct this Result view model in controller /service with appropriate data  and pass this view model to view.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Do I have to separate controllers or do I put it in the same one - how do I run two queries on the same controller?

Comment: you can put in the same controller and run the two queries and populate view model with data before pushing to view.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new ViewModel class with all the properties you want to display in your View. Then you model your View after it.

From the properties you provided so far, the class should look like this:

```
public class StudentViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public strign Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Then you do the value x property assignment

```
string query = "SELECT title, `first name`, surname FROM `STUDENT REGISTER`";
List<StudentViewModel> model = new List<StudentViewModel>();

using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query)) {
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            model.Add(new StudentViewModel
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["StudentNumber"]),
                Title = Convert.ToString(sdr["title"]),
                Name = Convert.ToString(sdr["first name"]),
                Surname = Convert.ToString(sdr["surname"])
            });
        }
    }

    con.Close();
}

return View(model);
```

Comment: how do I then run another query to get information from a separate table but display the information on the same page?

Comment: @Michael Are they linked by some column or are they completely separate?

Comment: completely separate but I will also have some that are related in this project

Comment: @Michael if they are completely separate, you define the ViewModel class like Hazarath Chillara suggested, run both queries and do the assignment in each query reading loop. I'll update my answer.